# Search for products only in parent class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How do I edit the search form below to search only in a specific category on woocommerce?

```
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://url-is-here.com">
        <div>
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for products" />
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://url-is-here.com">
    <div>
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">Search for:</label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search for products" />
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" />
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
        <input type="hidden" name="cat" id="cat" value="5" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This should limit the results to category with an id of 5.